# How to update row with unique column in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a row with `sku` column that must be unique. But when I try to update this row it doesn't happen because of this. How to avoid this with Doctrine ? Or I should write custom logic ?

```
if (!$this->uniqueSkuSpecification->isSatisfiedBy($request->getSku())) {
            return ErrorResponse::fromCustomError(
                'Product sku must be unique',
                'sku',
                Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
            );
        }
```

The way I am populating the data from `$request` (its DTO)
public function updateFields(UpdateProductCommand $request): Product
{
$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($this);

```
    foreach ($reflection->getProperties() as $property) {
        $field = ucfirst($property->getName());
        $getter = "get{$field}";
        $setter = "set{$field}";
        if (method_exists($this, $setter) && !empty($request->$getter())) {
            $this->$setter($request->$getter());
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**EDIT**:
I am saving/updating this way:

```
$this->entityManager->persist($product);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: If I understand it's not a doctrine issue but your `uniqueSkuSpecification` ?